# Check to see if user input is in a certain range C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple program to check the grade of a person and output what Letter it is. For example I want to check if the user entered a number between 60-69 and if so out put a 'D'.

Any answers would be helpful, Thank you

Comment: Please provide the code that you have so far.

Comment: Cool. so have you finished your program?

Comment: `if(n>=60 && n<=69){...}` Does that do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ask user to enter something into the consol you need, first, say him what to do by using [`std::cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout)

After that you should get what he inserted into the consol by using [`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin).

After that you can compare the value with different condition to get the letter you want(the grade). A simple way can be like user "Beta" put on comments.

```
if(n < 60)
    grade = "E";
else if(n >=60 && n <= 69)
    grade = "D";
else if(....
...
```